# How to add a video as background for all pages in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6

I am trying to add a video as the background for the Magento frontend. Is it possible to do it? Or would gif be a better idea, despite bigger size?

Comment: i think using gif file would be more convenient. If we use video then it might take time to load due to bigger in size and can impact on your site performance so i would suggest you to use gif.

Comment: A .mp4 file is about 80% smaller in size than compared to a .gif of the same quality.

Answer (score 0):

you can add any .gif image file in your page background and display it on frontside, so it will not take extra load time to all pages

1) copy your .gif file and paste into your custom theme at

> app/design/frontend/Custom/default/web/images

2) copy _styles.less and styles-l.less less files from vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/ **OR** use your own if you have
and paste into app/design/frontend/Custom/default/web/css/

at end of file add below css

```
body{
    background: url('../images/giphy.gif');
}
```

just make sure your gif image should be here app/design/frontend/Custom/default/web/images/giphy.gif

run this command

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

you will see gif image in all front pages